# Can I access breifcase configuration info through SOAP or REST API

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, configuration, offline

Is there anyway to retrieve briefcase configuration via the REST API (preferably) or SOAP API? More info on briefcase configuration [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=offline_manage_briefcase_config.htm&language=en_US).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Some things you can customize in a Salesforce organization aren’t available in Metadata API.

The following components can’t be retrieved or deployed with Metadata API, and changes to them must be made manually in each of your organizations:

- ...
- Offline Briefcase Configurations
- ..."

[source -  meta_unsupported_types](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_unsupported_types.htm)